# What is causing slow login redirect when debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

After the user enters a username/password and clicks a button a few steps happen:

1. Password is encrypted and checked against small database table (customMembershipProvider)
2. A query returns the users roles (customRoleMembershipProvider)
3. A query is run that returns about 30 records
4. `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userNameTextbox.Text, true);` is called
5. `Response.Redirect(@"~/Home.aspx", true);` is called
6. User arrives at simple html page

I have verified that it isn't the queries (1, 2, 3  been cached so it doesn't even hit the database).  The page that the user is redirected to is also cached and has no database logic on it.  In production it is much faster of course, but still not as snappy as I want. What could be causing this issue?  **Also, I noticed once I do login, the next time I login (same or different user) the user is redirected instantaneously.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the slowness was only caused by the following combination:

Windows 7 Ultimate, VS2010 Ultimate, Any CPU configuration

Fixed by adding an x86 debug configuration and using it instead of the Any CPU configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide more information on the problem. There doesnt' sound like there is too much wrong with your approach but without seeing the custom membership and role providers its impossible to determine the slowdown.

Try using a .net profiler such as [JetBrains DotTrace](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fprofiler%2F&rct=j&q=jetbrains%20dottrace&ei=PZnRTJi3Osf-4AbA3J3kDA&usg=AFQjCNGbmcIU7aPIZYLu465RUUms0Xaw6Q&sig2=AQGn7AwfVG-uUfirRbSoow&cad=rja) which will return a tree based graph of where the execution time has been concentrated. This should highlight the most serious hotspots which can usually make the problems far more obvious.

Comment: I highly doubt it has anything to do with the membership providers since the membership provider is only used to authenticate the user and when I camp out on both ends of the membership provider call it is not slow at all.

Comment: Have you tried building the app in release mode to determine if there's just a lot of debug info being worked through the first time?

Comment: Without having more of an example to recreate the problem I'd strongly suggest getting the trial of the DotTrace profiler. At least then you can see what's going on rather than guessing where the issue may lie.